# Get full website URL?

Tags: php

I have a function which looks like this:

```
function fullURL(){
    $domain = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
    $path = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    $raw_url = $domain.$path;
    $url = substr($raw_url, 0, -4);
    echo $url;
}
```

This generates an *URL* which looks like `127.0.0.1/aura/profile`
But, what if I would use this on a page which uses a **$_GET**-tag?

Then, my *URL* won't pick it up.
For example I have `news?id=1`, when using the function above it just becomes `127.0.0.1/aura/news`.
What do I need to add to the function to make it output `127.0.0.1/aura/news?id=(id)`?

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```
$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

Note that you could also do:

```
$actual_link = "http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
```

Original answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6768831/3150271

Comment: Please give attribution to the original author: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6768831/3150271  Otherwise, it is plagiarism.

Comment: I have marked the post as duplicate, but there you go.