# I can't get full url path

Tags: php

I have two buttons to change my language in my site..
i am getting the full url with

```
$myurl = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

And my two buttons:

```
echo '<a href="'.$myurl.'?lang=en"><img src="http://www.example.com/site/flags/en.png" name="English" title="English" alt="" width="40" height="40" border="0" ></a>';

echo '<a href="'.$myurl.'?lang=de"><img src="http://www.example.com/site/flags/de.png" name="German" title="German" alt="" width="40" height="40" border="0" ></a>';
```

So far it's working great... So if press the first button my url (in my url bar) will be

```
http://www.example.com/site/?lang=en
```

Now if i echo this `"http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`
I am getting `http://www.example.com/site/index.php` and in my url bar i can see

```
http://www.example.com/site/?lang=en
```

Does anybody know why i can't "grab" the ?lang=en?

I also tried the code bellow but without luck....

```
if ($string == "http://www.example.com/site/index.php" || $string == "http://www.example.com/site/" || $string == "http://www.example.com/site/?lang=en" || $string == "http://www.example.com/site/index.php?lang=en"){
echo "ENGLISH";
}else{
echo "DE";
}
```

Comment: ever heard of `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`? Just do `echo "<a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?lang=en'><img...."` It will not give you an absolute path with hostname in it, but it will work.

Comment: Please search first.  Literally the exact same question was asked yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23973574/get-full-website-url

Comment: Use "$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']" to get parametters !

Comment: It returns "/site/index.php"

Comment: I checked this liks but doesn't work for me...
My website is Wordpress.. Need i edit enything on it?
All these returns http://www.example.com/site/ Even in my url bar is http://www.example.com/site/?lang=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to read out `lang` from the url params?

```
if (!isset($_GET['lang']) || $_GET['lang'] == 'en')
    echo "ENGLISH";
else
    echo "DE";
```

If you just want to get the query string, to use in a link, use:

```
echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```

Or to remove the `?` when there is no query string:

```
echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']!=''?'?':'') . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```

Comment: Correct my friend... Great... missing $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']